# Не работает async await || react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, асинхронность

Я в useEffect вызываю функции из props, которые получаю из actions(redux). У меня есть action - setPostsRequest, который не вызывается последовательно, хотя я все делаю в async/await.

Вызов -

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function setPosts() {
        await props.setPostsRequest()
        props.setNumberToCounterPost(2)
        props.filterPosts()
    }
    setPosts()

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```

Сама функция -

[image: Сама функция]

Последовательность в redux devtools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я создаю store -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать миделварь thunk
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

**UPDATE**
Добавьте в перед `return async (dispatch)`
и перед `await axios.get`

`useEffect`  - должен быть **синхронным**!

**UPDTE2**

вот пример моей рабочей функции:

```
export function fetchData(page = 1) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SHOW_LOADER });
    await axios
      .get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos", {
        params: {
            //PARAMS
        },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_DATA,
          payload: { data: result.data, page: page },
        });
        dispatch({ type: HIDE_LOADER });
        dispatch({ type: TOTAL_PAGES, payload: result.headers["x-total"] });
      });
  };
}
```

в компонента где хотим получить данные импортируем:

`import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'`

далее

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData(1));
}, []);
```

потому что судя по вашему коду вы нигде не диспатчете `setPostsRequest()`

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Добавил как я создаю store

Comment: @mbfilipp дополнил ответ

Comment: тот же результат как и на картинке из redux devtools, асинхронный экшен сделал

Comment: @mbfilipp то покажите ваш код, а не скрины

Comment: какие фрагменты кода оставить? я добавлю в вопрос

Comment: @mbfilipp код компонента где вызывается `useEffect(()`  
а еще будет лучше если вы сделаете рабочий пример здесь https://codesandbox.io/
и прикрепите ссылку

Comment: @mbfilipp обновил ответ

Comment: сделал так как вы, получилось тоже самое, для проверки решил сделать setTimeout на все кроме setPostsRequest, в итоге получилось, но мне кажется это не правильная практика. Завтра попробую разобраться до конца с этой темой. Спасибо за обсуждение и помощь